# Need to call external function inside awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Here is my bash script

```
##################start#######################

 cat out.txt | awk -F'\n' '{ 
n=split($0,line,"[");
for (i = 2; i <= n;i++) {
    printf "%s [%s\n", line[1],line[i] ;

    ############ need to call netcat_output function here##########
}

}'

netcat_output () {
    echo $1``
}
####################end ########################
```

I need to call `netcat_output` function with `line[i]` argument. how can i do this ??

Comment: Show a sample input from `out.txt` and your expected output.

Comment: Btw: define a function in your code before you try to use it.

Comment: can you explain more or edit my code here ?

Comment: Move your code (three lines) of your function `netcat_output` to a line before `cat out.txt | awk ...`.

Comment: My take would be "you can't".  Convert function into a script and maybe there's a chance.  More likely, it is time to use Perl or Python instead, writing the function in that language.

Comment: ok done... how can i call function.. ? like this ?

`netcat_output line[i]`

Comment: Show input/wanted output/motivation. We can help better when we understand your problem. Is `[`a field seperator? Do you really want to print `line[1]` in front of all other fields of your line? Can it be done with a simple `while IFS="[" read -r var1 var2 var3 ; do .. done < out.txt`. Just give some examples.

Comment: `system("netcat ...")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this template for your problem.  Namely, define and export your function before the `awk` statement.  Also explicitly define `bash` in your system call, otherwise by default it will be a `sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function f() {
   echo $RANDOM
}

export -f f

awk 'BEGIN{print system("bash -c '\'' f '\'' ")}'
```